# updating two asp.net partial views using one jquery post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am working on an asp.net application. I have an action method which deletes items and refreshes the partial view like this:

```
 $(".removeCartItem").click(function () {

            if (confirm("Click OK if you want to delete this record; otherwise, click 'Cancel'")) {

                var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
                if (recordToDelete != '') {                      
                    $.post("/Cart/DeleteCartItem", { "id": recordToDelete },
                        function (data) {                               
                            $("#divStore").html(data);                             
                        });
                }
            }
            return false; 

        });
```

and here is the action method

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteCartItem(int Id)
        {

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                ItemBiz.DeleteItemFromCart(Id);
            }
           return RedirectToAction("ReturnView");

        }
```

and other action method which repopulates partial view:

```
 public ActionResult ReturnView()
        {
            CheckoutModel oCheckoutModel = new CheckoutModel();
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                int CustomerId = MembershipBiz.GetCustomerIDByUserID(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
                //if (deliveryDate != null)
                oCheckoutModel.AllCartItems = ItemBiz.GetCartItemsByCustomerID(CustomerId);
            }

            List<CartInfoByStore> model = oCheckoutModel.AllCartItems;

            int count = model.Count();
            return PartialView("_CheckoutItemsList", model);
        }
```

I have another partial view where i need to update the count , but I am not sure how to pass the count from this action method to that partial view on success of above jquery post method.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

I made another call to another action method after deletion. If someone finds better solution, Please suggest.

```
 $(".removeCartItem").click(function () {

            if (confirm("Click OK if you want to delete this record; otherwise, click 'Cancel'")) {

                var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
                if (recordToDelete != '') {
                    // Perform the ajax post
                    $.post("/Cart/DeleteCartItem", { "id": recordToDelete },
                        function (data) {
                            $("#divStore").html(data);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/Cart/GetCartCount',
                                type: "POST",
                            }).done(function (count) {
                                $('#spCartCount').text(count);
                            });

                        });
                }
            }
            return false; 

        });
```

Comment: Hey, I was facing a similar problem as well. And used the same method. Another AJAX call on success to update my 2nd partial view. Any new insights on this one so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is only to update the cart count after the list of cart items have been displayed, one thing I can suggest is to keep a hidden element in your _CheckoutItemsList partial view with the value as count. Once the partial view has rendered through ajax, you can copy the count from the hidden element to the required element.